# Boost.Asio or Libuv, which is better for large-scale Linux Servers for enterprise?(by c++)

Tags: linux, postgresql, server, libuv, asio

Boost.Asio or Libuv, which is better for large-scale Linux Servers for enterprise?(by c++)
The database will be PostgreSQL.
And the client should be app on iPhone and Android.
ps. Is golang very popular and effecient right now for Server developing? will golang work good with PostgreSQL and iphone & android?
thank you !

Comment: This is not really a good question for Stack Overflow. Based on the few requirements supplied, it sounds a lot like a collection of opinionated answers. You should probably take this to a [Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @jww thank you. 1st time asking question here.